# grub rescue error: symbol 'grub_strchrnul' not found

Tags: linux, boot, grub, centos-7

I was testing another distro and deleted it but forgot to re-install grub into the main drive with Centos 7. Now when booting the system it takes me to grub rescue since mbr is trying to boot from the deleted partition.

I set the root, prefix correctly, however, when running `insmod normal` or `insmod linux` i get this error message:

`error: symbol 'grub_strchrnul' not found.`

i can insert some other modules with no issue such as (reboot, hello, cat)

Currently I have no bootable CD or flash and trying to fix this from with in the grub rescue, is it possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue after try to update grub config for this OS.

Please try to replace content of `/boot/grub2/i386-pc/` folder from another instance of installed Centos 7 or bootable media. 
I had boot from recovery boot CD and have copied this folder from another Centos 7 server over network.

Also I suggest create backup copy of `/boot/grub2/` folder to to facilitate recovery in the future, e.g. `/boot/grub2bak/`.